# What does the Modern Warfare PS4 digital copy contain?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare

Before buying the digital copy of Modern Warfare, despite checking their website, I'm still anxious if the campaign and the online game modes like ground war etc. will be included in the digital copy. Can anyone share their feedback for those who had bought the digital copy?